# Strange Characters on terminal

Tags: c

Could someone explain me, why I'm getting these strange characters on output?

I got this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    if(argc!=2){
        printf("Incorrect number of arguments\n");
        return -1;
    }
    int lenServer=0;
    int i=0;
    while(argv[1][i]!=':'){
        lenServer++;
        i++;
    }

    char server[lenServer];
    memcpy(server,argv[1],lenServer);

    printf("%s\n",server);
    return 1;

}
```

I got this on terminal:

```
pedro@pedro-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/SDMEU$ gcc table_client.c -o table-client
pedro@pedro-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/SDMEU$ ./table-client ola:eu
ola N
pedro@pedro-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/SDMEU$
```

Shouldn't I just get `ola`?

Comment: `server` is not `'\0'` terminated, and declare it as `char server[lenServer + 1];` , +1 for `'\0'`

Comment: So what sould i do? its curious, cuz if i put a printf("%s\n",lenServer); just before creating the array server[], i get what it suppose to get :S

Comment: remember char array are different then string in C, a valid string is always nul terminated char array, `"%s"` use to print string you before to print it you must at `'\0'` as end char in `server[]` as answered below.

Answer (score 2):

put a NUL(`'\0'`) to the end of the string.

```
char server[lenServer+1];
memcpy(server,argv[1],lenServer);
server[lenServer]=0;
```

Comment: ok. it worked. can you explain me server[lenServer]=0; this? just dont get it. and thx :)

Comment: @PedroViana E.g "ola" , lenServer : 3,  `char server[lenServer+1];` => `char server[4];` `server[0]`:`o`, `server[1]`:`l`, `server[2]`:`a`, `server[3]`:`\0`,

Comment: @PedroViana Note int equivalent value of `'\0'` nul symbol is `0` so in bluepixy's answer `server[lenServer] = 0;` is same in effect as of  `server[lenServer] = '\0';` Both are same.